# How to make this photoshop ribbon navigation work and be responsive?

Tags: navigation, zurb-foundation, ribbon, nav

I found a really awesome ribbon navigation that I'd like to use but it is just a Photoshop file, no code or anything. At first I thought, I'll be able to figure something out but now I think it might be way above my skill level. I'm designing the site to be responsive using Foundation. If anyone has any idea on how to make this work or even a similar kind work, that'd be awesome. I was going to just drop the whole thing (after I customized it) in as an image and take the cheap way out and do an image map but that's just not going to work. I'd love for the little tag to actually drop down when you hover over the parent (luckily, I only have one drop down menu in the nav I need) and for the ribbon to raise up like that (simple hover image?). Anyways, if the short answer is "you're crazy, try something else" then that's totally fine. I'd rather it be responsive and work than be gerry-rigged.

http://www.designkindle.com/2010/10/28/elegant-ribbon-menu/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this but probably not with an image map. It you wanted an animation to occur when you hover over a certain part of the ribbon you may need to use Flash or Silverlight (That is a project in itself). Gifs might work though. Then you could do a image map. I have never attempted this myself but you may have yourself a project -- I would use Jquery heavily.

Comment: 0 experience with Flash/Silverlight so that's not going to work. If I did an image map I wouldn't have any animation, I would just have the tag sitting there at all times. Thanks for the input!

Comment: So here's what I did. I put the entire image into a div. I set the div to max-width: 100% and height: auto. The div is also set to 5 columns (using Foundation). Then I image mapped it and used some code I found to make the image map responsive down to 961px. At a 960px breakpoint, I have it coded to switch to a drop down list using media query... That's an extremely simplified breakdown of what I did but just thought I'd share :)